# Filter object-array with map and forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

I want to filter an array object (list1) and give back an object that looks like this based on people's meal preferences.

```
let allPeople = { vegetarian: 1, standard: 2, vegan: 0 }
```

Here is the list:

```
let list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Noah', lastName: 'M.', country: 'Switzerland', continent: 'Europe', age: 19, language: 'C', 
    meal: 'vegetarian' },
  { firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'K.', country: 'Liechtenstein', continent: 'Europe', age: 52, language: 'JavaScript', 
    meal: 'standard' },
{ firstName: 'Andi', lastName: 'R.', country: 'Liechtenstein', continent: 'Europe', age: 62, language: 'JavaScript', 
    meal: 'standard' }]
```

Here is my code:

```
let allPeople = list1.forEach((el)=>{

let mealTypes={vegetarian: 0, standard: 0, vegan: 0}

if (el.meal==='vegetarian') {
  mealTypes['vegetarian'] +=1;
  }

else if (el.meal ==='standard') {
  mealTypes['standard'] +=1;
  }

else if (el.meal === 'vegan') {
  mealTypes['vegan'] +=1;
  }

return mealTypes;
}
)

console.log(allPeople)
```

When I invoke the function it returns 'undefined'. Thanks for reading or even helping a beginner out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate the wanted data.

```js
let list1 = [
  { firstName: 'Noah', lastName: 'M.', country: 'Switzerland', continent: 'Europe', age: 19, language: 'C', 
    meal: 'vegetarian' },
  { firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'R.', country: 'Liechtenstein', continent: 'Europe', age: 52, language: 'JavaScript', 
    meal: 'standard' }];
    
let res = list1.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (acc[cur.meal]===undefined)
        acc[cur.meal] = 1;
    else
        acc[cur.meal]++;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This means that you need to instantiate an object while having knowledge of what possible `meal` values to track.

Comment: @Terry - I made it intentionally so because the OP wanted to count the zero-elements `vegan: 0` but I changed it. It depends what you want if you need to instantiate or not.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that in the `forEach()` loop, you are resetting the `mealTypes` object. You can solve this by using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which helps to collate the counts on the `meal` property on each encountered item in the list:

```
let allPeople = list1.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.meal] = acc[el.meal]++ || 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Basically, you start the accumulator with an empty object, `{}`. Then, at each iteration, you attempt to increment a possible number in the object, accessed by its key, i.e. `acc[el.meal]`. When it does not exist, `acc[el.meal]++` will return `NaN` (which is falsy) and you simply seed it with an initial value of `1`. If it exists, then you effectively increment it.

The advantage of this method is that you:

- do not create an object outside the scope of the `reduce` method
- do not need to know all the possible values of `meal` in your array of objects, as the reduce function will simply add a new entry when it encounters a new unique value

Of course, if you want to make full use of ES6, you can use object destructuring... but it might look a bit complicated if you're not used to the syntax:

```
let allPeople = list1.reduce((acc, { meal }) => {
  acc[meal] = acc[meal]++ || 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
let list1 = [{
    firstName: 'Noah',
    lastName: 'M.',
    country: 'Switzerland',
    continent: 'Europe',
    age: 19,
    language: 'C',
    meal: 'vegetarian'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Anna',
    lastName: 'R.',
    country: 'Liechtenstein',
    continent: 'Europe',
    age: 52,
    language: 'JavaScript',
    meal: 'standard'
  }
];

let allPeople = list1.reduce((acc, { meal }) => {
  acc[meal] = acc[meal]++ || 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(allPeople);
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer Terry, I actually just tried it out now and unfortunately it just returns 1 or 0 based on whether there are people that eat vegetarian, standard etc. but does not actually count how many people eat standard etc. I changed the example in my original post to make it a bit more clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of javascript's `forEach` is `undefined`, which is what you're seeing here.

If you instead initialize the `mealTypes` collection outside of the `forEach` and then use the `forEach` to modify that collection, you'll get what you're looking for.

```js
let mealTypes={vegetarian: 0, standard: 0, vegan: 0}

list1.forEach((el)=>{
  if (el.meal==='vegetarian') {
    mealTypes['vegetarian'] +=1;
  }
  else if (el.meal ==='standard') {
    mealTypes['standard'] +=1;
  }
  else if (el.meal === 'vegan') {
    mealTypes['vegan'] +=1;
  }
});

console.log(mealTypes);
```